# visual basic 2010 -- alternate of Alt+Tab

Tags: .net, vb.net, process

I want to:

1. set "Hello!" on the clipboard
2. alt tab to last active window (e.g. notepad, etc)
3. paste what's on the clipboard

The way I have it implemented works, but not flawlessly; it works most of the times, other times, it simply won't do step 2.
I've tried other events such as "Click", "MouseUp" and as you can see below, "MouseClick".
Is there any alternate way of implementing the alt+tab?
Frustrated and need your help. Thanks!

---

I have "System.Threading" imported.
sample code:

```
Private Sub try1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles try1.MouseClick
        Clipboard.Clear() 'clears the clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText("Hello!")
        SendKeys.Send("%{Tab}")
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        SendKeys.SendWait("+{Insert}")
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the process name of the current active window to activate it later, you can store it in a dictionary or a list or tuple or anything else.

Then use **AppActivate** to activate the desired window that you want instead trying to send tab keys to try to return to the last active window.

```
#Region " App Activate "

' [ App Activate ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
' Examples :
'
' App_Activate("notepad")
' App_Activate("notepad.exe")

Private Sub App_Activate(ByVal ProcessName As String)

    ProcessName = If(ProcessName.ToLower.EndsWith(".exe"), _
                     ProcessName.Substring(0, ProcessName.LastIndexOf(".")), _
                     ProcessName)

    AppActivate(Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName).FirstOrDefault.Id)

End Sub

#End Region
```

Comment: This is nicely implemented. Thank you so much, Elektro Hacker!

Comment: @user2889072 Thank You, please feel free to mark the answer as 'accepted' if the code has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys has a second method you should try:

```
SendKeys.SendWait()
```

The problem is Send() puts the message in the queue and continues on while SendWait() will pause until the message is processed in windows message queue.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the input,Steve! I'll give this a shot!